# How to exclude user from "people" group in Sun Java System Messaging Server 6.3?

Tags: java, email, openldap

I am new at Sun Java System Messaging Server 6.3. I am managing my e-mail users and group via ldapbrowser version 2.8.2.

I want to exclude a particular user from people group.

I found the below string in people group's configuration:

```
memberURL: ldap:///o=domain.com,dc=domain,dc=com??sub?(&(Employeenumber=*)(InetUserStatus=active))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The definition of the 'People' group is:

> Within `ldap:///o=domain.com,dc=domain,dc=com`, where the attribute `Employeenumber` is present (`Employeenumber=*`), and the attribute `InetUserStatus` has the value `active` (`InetUserStatus=active`).

So, if you want to *exclude* someone, you need and attribute to match, and the value to exclude and construct the LDAP search filter that matches this, and update the filter `(&(Employeenumber=*)(InetUserStatus=active))` to correspond to this.

so, if they were `Employeenumber` `55`, then you don't want them in the list, so the condition for this is `!(Employeenumber=55)`, so you need to plug this into the selection condition as:

```
(&(&(Employeenumber=*)(InetUserStatus=active))(!(Employeenumber=55)))
```

If you wanted to filter a second user (e.g. `Employeenumber` `99` as well, then it becomes:

```
(&(&(&(Employeenumber=*)(InetUserStatus=active))(!(Employeenumber=55)))(!(Employeenumber=99)))
```

You can see how this will get very complicated very quickly.

Comment: I have noticed that multiple employees have same employeeNumber i.e; 329. Can I use any other attribute such as uidNumber(which is consist of the name of user)?

Comment: Yes, I was using `employeeNumber` as an example - you need to decide on the filter attribute to use and the value to use as well.

Comment: When I am adding this attribute the e-mail is not receiving at the people group.

Comment: Have you validated your filter? If there's an error then you would see nobody in the list - test the filter you've used via the `search` option of the ldap browser. It's really easy to make a mistake with the filter when you write it by hand (I typoed the second one when I entered it).

Comment: I've done it by changing the employeenumber of the specific user and than follow your instructions. Thanks alot!